# on hover increase node radius

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover, force-layout

[Link to my code (Plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/GaoBUfQv3uvTjNrsIPZ3?p=preview)

I am developing a network diagram in D3.js force layout I am stuck with a mouse over functionality. When I hover a node, I want the links and children (one hop) associated with it to expand in size. Right now, my code increases the size of the hovered node and links associated with it but not the nodes associated with it.

This is what I have tried so far,

On mouse over the hovered node will expand -

```
function mouseover(d) {
    link.style('stroke-width', function(l) {
    if (d === l.source || d === l.target)
        return 4;
    });

    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
    .duration(300)
    .attr("r", 12);
}
```

On mouse out the hovered node will go back to same size as it was before -

```
function mouseout() {
    link.style('stroke-width', 1.5);
    d3.select(this).select("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a few for loops to get this through:

Inside the mouseover function do this:

```
//links for which source or traget is hovered       
var filtered = link.filter(function(l){
  return (d === l.source || d === l.target);
})
filtered.style("stroke-width", 4);
//select all the data associated with the link i.e. source and target data
var selectedData = [];
filtered.each(function(f){
  selectedData.push(f.source);
  selectedData.push(f.target);
});
//select all the circles for which we have collected the data above.
var circleDOM = [];
selectedData.forEach(function(sd){
  d3.selectAll("circle")[0].forEach(function(circle){
    console.log(d3.select(circle).data()[0].name, sd.name)
    if (d3.select(circle).data()[0].name == sd.name){
      circleDOM.push(circle);//collect all the DOM Elements for which the data matches.
    }
  });
});
//do transition with all selected DOMs
d3.selectAll(circleDOM).transition()
    .duration(300)
    .attr("r", 12);
```

working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uOPfJw4wEvOZvrdP15kn?p=preview)

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for! May I know what you mean by this line, `d3.selectAll("circle")[0].forEach(function(circle){})` and why not `d3.selectAll("circle").forEach(function(circle){})`?

Comment: `d3.selectAll("circle")[0]` //this will give you the DOM elements ie. all the circle DOMs in the SVG.
later in the foreach loop i do `d3.select(circle).data()[0]` this will get the data bound to that circle.

Comment: Thanks @Cyril. A follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649329/filter-nodes-and-edges-according-to-user-preference