# How to approach filtering nodes and edges rendered via d3.js according to user preference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, force-layout

[Link to my code (Plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/bprO5PL6OSlkto4BzaD0?p=preview)

I am developing a network diagram in D3.js force layout for academic purpose. I have so far coded a graph which displays nodes and edges. I have an auto-complete text box in jquery where user can enter a node name.

D3.js (Only part of code. For complete code see my plunker link):

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
  .links(links)
  .size([width, height])
  .linkDistance(100)
  .charge(-1546)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start();

var svg = d3.select("#schemio")
  .append('svg')
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Filter: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Jquery (Autocomplete)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: nodesArray
    });
});
```

I want a functionality where when a user enters a node name in the filter box, I need to remove all other nodes and edges in the graph and keep only that particular node and its directly associated nodes and edges (one hop).

Example:

When I type "Parent" in the filter box it has to remove all other nodes and edges and keep only "Parent" node and its direct child nodes (child1, child2, child3).

[image]

**What is a viable approach for filtering nodes and edges as the user searches for particular terms?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't exactly know what's the concrete question. Where are you stuck with your code right know?

Comment: Actually! I am new to D3.js and I am experimenting with this network diagram. I would like to like to know what would be the best approach if I need a functionality that I described in my question. I saw many examples each has been implemented in its own way. Example this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/Bf5nM/light/) uses filter function whereas I saw one another example where they manually parse all the nodes in the graph and perform highlighting functionality.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've edited your question so that the intention of it becomes more clear. It's a worthwhile question, so I'm trying to answer it.

Comment: Sure! Thanks. Also, I have removed my mouse-over and mouse-out event code as it is irrelevant to the question that I have asked.

Comment: Thanks for removing the mouse-over / mouse-out code. Makes it easier to see what's the question / problem. Hope my question helps you. I suggest to take a look at the example I've linked to in my answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**In essence**, what a user is doing by searching for a specific node name is to **narrow the data the visualization is going to show**.

### The approach

1. First you need to narrow down the source data by using filtering or whatever makes sense in your situation. You end up with **filtered data**.
2. Then you need to `selectAll` the nodes that have been drawn already and **join** the `selection` with **filtered data** from step 1.
3. Finally use the d3 `enter`, `update` and `exit` selections to add, update and **remove** nodes and links.

### Example

Mike Bostock published an example of [Modifying a Force Layout].(https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795)